# Kendo UI Highlight Text in Grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to highlight text within a Kendo grid.  I am using [jQuery Highlight Plugin](http://bartaz.github.com/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html)! to highlight the text.

I am able to use the highlight plugin against plain old html grids.  However, when I try to reference a grid generated by Kendo, I cannot get the highlight to work.

Here is a snippet of the code from my MVC page.

```
<div id="grid">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()...
</div>
```

I looked at the rendered code with my browser (IE, Chrome), and noticed there was a <script> tag associated with the grid.  I took the rendered HTML and <script> tag from the browser and plugged into my page to verify highlight is working.

When I remove the following  tag, highlight works.  When it appears in the appear, highlighting does not work.

```
<script>
        jQuery(function () { jQuery("#grid6cbf1150-e10f-4df3-890b-85d9b3e754e0").kendoGrid( ... ); });
</script>
```

So the question is, what is this  tag doing to prevent the highlight from working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the hightlight demo and it seems to be working fine. Check the following example I created:

Do not forget to add the styles to your page so you can see the actual hightlight:

```
<style>
.highlight {
    background-color: #FFFF88;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ehnSq/18/

Comment: The highlight does work when the <script> is not in the rendered code.  When the <script> tag is rendered by Kendo, the <span> tag does not generated by the jQuery Highlight Plugin.

Comment: The solution was to add an Event to the Kendo UI Grid.  I added `".Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))"`.  In the javascript function for `onDataBound`, add a reference to the highlight plugin.