# Highlight All Ocurrences of a word in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to highlight all the occurences of a word the kendo grid?

The cell can contain multiple strings, if the word is in that string, I just want it highlighted?

My Grid looks like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
      .Name("searchGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.Title).Width(140);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(100);
          columns.Bound(p => p.TheString).Width(200).Encoded(false);
      })
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
      .Groupable()
      .Scrollable()
      .Selectable()
      .Filterable()
      .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "height:430px;"})
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Server()
          .PageSize(20)
          .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.RowId))
      ).Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
      )
```

I am about to try something like this:

```
      columns.Bound(p => p.TheString).Width(200).Encoded(false).Template(@<text>
    @if (item.TheString.Contains(@ViewBag.SearchString))
    {
        <div style="background-color: Red;">
            @item.TheString
        </div>
    } else
    {
        <div style="background-color: Green;">
            @item.TheString
        </div>              
    }          
</text>)
```

I am using VS 2012 MVC 4 C#

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much same question is covered in [this post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505575/kendo-ui-highlight-text-in-grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That functionality is not included in Kendo UI, but you can use [this jQuery plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html), for example, which allows you to highlight via

```
$("#searchGrid").highlight("mytext");
```